# Вопросы вместо юникода в консоли

Tags: powershell, unicode

[image: Консоль PyCharm] [image: Powershell]

На этих двух скриншотах powershell в PyCharm и обычный. Проблема что обычный не прогружает символы юникода правильно

Пробовал менять кодировку через `$PSDefaultParameterValues['Out-File:Encoding'] = 'utf8'`, но не помогло

С чем могло бы быть связано?

**Дополнительные сведения**

1. Изменение `chcp` на 65001 не помогло
2. Проблема исходит от символов кодом от 9600 до 9607, 9608 (обычный блок) выводит, как видите, нормально. Проблема только там, где остаток
3. [Ссылка на вывод программы](https://mega.nz/file/ImxAWCbC#2AoEuuJpuxmJACn7KaldK-LCchWWP8SBToPAPKRfx4Q)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Это может быть связано с тем, что в консоли не utf8

Comment: @user7860670 ну скорее всего с этим и проблема. А как переключить-то? Вышел писал, что пробовал, но не помогло

Comment: Скорее надо переключить вывод в печатающей программе на utf16

Comment: Вопросы могут быть по двум причинам. Во-первых, при форматировании вывода могли обрезать юникодные символы, если выходная кодировка не юникодная. Что у вас в `$OutputEncoding` и `[Console]::Out`?
Во-вторых, сама консоль может быть настроена на неюникодную страницу. Какую кодовую страницу вам печатает команда `chcp`? Если там что-то отличное от 65001, то можно назначить юникодный ввод/вывод окна консоли командой `chcp 65001`.

Comment: Есть ещё вариант со шрифтами. У меня в консоли VS Code показывает почти все символы из тестового файла Unicode https://www.ltg.ed.ac.uk/~richard/unicode-sample.html, а в обычной консоли только Latin, IPA и кириллицу. Нет ни иероглифов, ни еврейского алфавита, ни арабского, ни индийских. Не удивлюсь, если псевдографика поддерживается кусками. Выложите куда-нибудь тестовый файл с выводом вашей программы, чтобы попробовать его с разными настройками консоли.

Comment: Да, дело в шрифте. Выбранный по умолчанию шрифт Lucida Console поддерживает довольно ограниченный набор символов Unicode. Если выбрать ,например, DejaVu Sans Mono, этот символ будет отображаться.

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight да, проблема была в этом, спасибо)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$OutputEncoding указывает на то что вывод происходит в кодировке windows-1252 (WindowsCodePage: 1252) а не в unicode она называется западноевропейская или latin1.

А консоль работает с кодовой страницей 866 которая схожа с Koi8-r где все специфические европейские символы во второй половине заменены на кириллицу. Проще всего установить chcp 1252 или 850, тогда консоль будет работать на западноевропейской однобайтовой кодировке как и вывод в неё. Но могут быть проблемы с русскими символами. Второй вариант это настроить вывод в Pycharm и установить там cp1251

Но можно попробовать установить utf8 и там и там

Для настройки вывода Pycharm https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/working-with-consoles.html

```
On the Help menu, click Edit Custom VM Options.

Add the -Dconsole.encoding option and set the value to the necessary encoding. For 
example: -Dconsole.encoding=UTF-8

Restart PyCharm.
```

Для консоли

```
chcp 65001 //utf8
chcp 850   //западноевропейская DOS
chcp 1252  //западноевропейская ANSI 
chcp 866   //кириллическая DOS
chcp 1251  //кириллическая ANSI
```

Точно не скажу будет ли utf8 адекватно работать в PS сам мучаюсь пишу для CLI PHP модули. Браузер, андроид и мускул воспринимают utf8 как надо а вот вывод в консоль кривой что только не пытался сделать chcp 65001 не помогает приходится вывод для консоли вручную конвертировать, благо в php это легко `$str= iconv('utf-8', 'cp866', $str);`